# How to send dynamic html table in email body using java

Tags: java, html

I have a class callProcedure which has method getProductwiseCount.

Through callprocedure class I am calling sendMail method of another class.I want to generate dynamic table from key and value pairs from hashmap in html and attached it in mail. How do I do it?

```
public HashMap<Long, String> getProductwiseCount() {
        return ProductwiseCount;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean about 'dynamic'? Email accepts only static html, so you should pre-generate it before sending

Comment: @Beloo By dynamic table means value coming from hashmap

Comment: @Beloo okay I did it by pre-genrating html string and pass it as parameter in sendEmail method. It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
I did it by pre-generating html in callProcedure class. Save it in to String and passed it in a sendEmail method.

  String text=
         "<table width='100%' border='1' align='center'>"
                + "<tr align='center'>"
                + "<td><b>Product Name <b></td>"
                + "<td><b>Count<b></td>"
                + "</tr>";

    for (Map.Entry entry : ProductwiseCount.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " :" + entry.getValue());
                    text=text+"<tr align='center'>"+"<td>" + entry.getValue() + "</td>"
                                + "<td>" + entry.getKey() + "</td>"+"</tr>";

                }

 sendMail.sendMail(host, port, to, from,text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its to easy to add html into email body. Just create HTML you want to add into body and set to message body part,Check this:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/